# Is it possible to specify minimum tokens for staking elections?

Tags: staking, election

I would like to know if `pallet-staking` has any mechanism that facilitates constraints upon the amount of tokens that can be staked. I think polkadot initially came with no particular requirement for minimum stake, but in the chain I am building, I would like to have a minimum stake for the validator to be considered for elections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pallet itself provides for this, and there is (at the time of writing) a proposal to do just what you are after on Polkadot: https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/post/905

Here is the type described: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_staking/type.MinValidatorBond.html

And here is the call to set it in source: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/21cadf1af453716aea1e5362c83aa314811da657/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L1530-L1561

Comment: That's neat, I hadn't looked at the staking source code before asking this, another way I see is a parameter in staking's genesis config, so that leaves us with two ways of setting this right?

Comment: yup! although querying the chain storage for this is best, as it can change :)